# Computing ROC curve for K-NN classifier

Tags: machine-learning, knn, roc

As you probably know, in K-NN, the decision is usually taken according to the "majority vote", and not according to some threshold - i.e. **there is no parameter to base a ROC curve on**.

Note that in the implementation of my K-NN classifier, the votes don't have equal weights. I.e. the weight for each "neighbor" is ***e^(-d)***, where ***d*** is the distance between the tested sample and the neighbor. This measure gives higher weights for the votes of the nearer neighbors among the K neighbors.

---

**My current decision rule** is that if the sum of the scores of the positive neighbors is higher than the sum of the scores of the negative samples, then my classifier says ***POSITIVE***, else, it says ***NEGATIVE***.

**But - There is no threshold**.

---

---

Then,  I thought about the following idea:

***Deciding on the class of the samples which has a higher sum of votes, could be more generally described as using the threshold 0, for the score computed by:*** ***(POS_NEIGHBORS_SUMMED_SCORES - NEG_NEIGHBORS_SUMMED_SCORES)***

---

So I thought changing my decision rule to be using a threshold on that measure, and plotting a ROC curve basing on thresholds on the values of

***(POS_NEIGHBORS_SUMMED_SCORES - NEG_NEIGHBORS_SUMMED_SCORES)***

Does it sound like a good approach for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is more or less what is typically used. If you take a look at scikit-learn it has weights in knn, and they also have predit_proba, which gives you a clear decision threshold. Typically you do not want to condition on a difference, however, but rather ratio

```
votes positive / (votes negative + votes positive) < T
```

this way, you know that you just have to "move" threshold from 0 to 1, and not arbitrary values. it also now has a clear interpretation - as an internal probability estimate that you consider "sure enough". By default T = 0.5, if the probability is above 50% you classify as positive, but as said before - you can do anything wit it.